# Isomorphic fetch do not pass file when credentials are set to 'same-origin'

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am using [isomorphic fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) and using [Formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

When I am trying to post/ request **formdata** using isomorphic-fetch-api, there are two cases which is kind of unexpected behaviour as respect to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials). (Note: formdata here includes file object)

1. When adding `credentials: include`, then the request is passed without cookies. (And backend and frontend are running on the same server so may not need to add 'include' anyway)
2. And when adding `credentials: same-origin`, then the cookies are passed. But problem I am facing in this case is with formdata. When passing the data using formdata (which includes a file object), the data which is posted to backend do not include file object and rest of the values are available.

And the third case when adding no credentials, then there is no cookies passed and nothing can be done without cookies.

Not too sure about, what is causing this behaviour either Formdata or Fetch or Credentials. Please help me in understanding if there is something I am missing in my approach.